# 'No converter found ' error while passing Date to postman

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, serialization, jackson

Im trying to create an appointment. I am trying to pass Date into Postman query, I have attempted to make a converter, but I get this error:
[image]

Here is my entity class code:

```
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Appointment extends BaseEntity {

    @NotNull
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIME)
    @DateTimeFormat(style = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ")
    @JsonFormat(shape=JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern="yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ")
    private Date startDate;

    @NotNull
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIME)
    @DateTimeFormat(style = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ")
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ")
    private Date endDate;
```

As you can see I have tried to make a converted, but have no clue why it is not working. Here are my libraries:
[image]

My appointmentDTO class:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public abstract class AppointmentDTO extends BaseDTO {

    @JsonProperty("start_date")
    private Date startDate;

    @JsonProperty("end_date")
    private Date endDate;

    @JsonProperty("user_id")
    private User user;

    private Set<Activity> activities;
}
```

Comment: Can you post your com.project.rushhour.model.get.AppointmentGetDTO class? I think you don't have public getters and setters in the AppointmentGetDTO class.

Comment: @mkashi Please [edit] the question and update code of `com.project.rushhour.model.get.AppointmentGetDTO` as suggested by @Abhinav. This will help in answering the question.

Comment: Done. I use lombok for them so this is not the problem

Comment: As `AppointmentGetDTO` is abstract, you need to write custom deserializer. Also, it is a good practice to have inputs, error logs, etc in text format in question rather than images.

Comment: I am using a non abstract class which inherits it and I am using it

Answer (score 0):

Add this configuration:

```
  @Configuration
  public class DateTimeFormatConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

   @Override
   public void addFormatters(FormatterRegistry registry) {
      DateTimeFormatterRegistrar registrar = new DateTimeFormatterRegistrar();
      registrar.setUseIsoFormat(true);
      registrar.registerFormatters(registry);
 }
}
```

In my controller it receives an ISO formatted date:

So `reistrar.setUseIsoFormat(true)` makes sure that Spring will parse the dates as ISO. Which means you have to make sure your dates are in the correct ISO format. When passing the date to a repository method you don't need to do anything special, you just keep it as a string.

Also in your entity I recommend you use `LocalDateTime` or `LocalDate` instead of `Date`.

```
@Column(name = "student_date_of_birth")
private LocalDate studentDateOfBirth; // 2020-05-20
```